# How are singularities of complex functions classified?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the function $$\frac{z^2+1}{z^3+6z^2+z}$$ And I wish to find the residues at $z_0=0$ and $z_0=2\sqrt{2}-3$ because they are within my given contour. However, I am really confused when it comes to classifying these singularities. I am pretty sure neither is removable because it looks like there is no value to assign to these points to make the function entire.

Comment: Remember that there are three possibilities for singularities: removable, pole, essential. You seem to have ruled out removable. Do you know what a pole is?

Comment: No, it's easier with rational functions like this one. You have a pole at $z_0$ when $f(z)(z-z_0)^n$ is analytic and nonzero for some positive integer $n$.

Comment: Why you don't use  Cauchy's  Integral Formula?

Comment: You should also factor the quadratic in the denominator, and then express it as a combination of $(z-2\sqrt2+3)^{-1}$ and $(z+2\sqrt2-3)^{-1})$.